# How do I make elements in jQuery Selectable deselected?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

How do I make elements in jQuery Selectable deselected? At this [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_selectable.htm) it is well documented how to use jQuery Selectable but it is never mentioned how to deselect selected elements again. Any ideas?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();

            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<ol id="selectable">
    <?php
        for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++) {
            echo "<li id=\"field_$i\" class=\"ui-state-default\">$i</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: You mean programatically? Because you can hold the control key down and click a selected element to de-select it.

Comment: Yes, programatically.

Comment: You can just remove the class that gets added to a selected list item, `ui-selected`.

Comment: No success with "$('#selectable .ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');"

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7FV6J/. Select the whole list and then wait a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and click on the elements. It can also be used to make multiple selections.

Comment: I would like to code it like: if one element in selectable is selected then deselect it.

Comment: Yes I did have a look, also in the API.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718493/how-to-implement-toggle-functionality-on-jquery-ui-selectable