# Toggle elemnts in selectable on mouse click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable, jquery-ui-widget

What I need to achieve is

1)i can select several element with every click.

2)When I click on the selected element again, It should be deselected

HTML CODE :

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#feedback {
    font-size: 1.4em; }
#selectable .ui-selecting {
     background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected {
     background: #F39814;
     color: white; }
#selectable {
     list-style-type:
     none; margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 60%; }
#selectable li {
     margin: 3px;
     padding: 0.4em;
     font-size: 1.4em;
     height: 18px; }
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});
```

[view this code in jquery site](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/)

Comment: can you be more specific about your requirement? do you want to show all clicked element as selected?

Comment: i want when clicked on element its be selected and when again clicked on this, its be deselected.

Comment: and what's the issue?

Comment: @RuneFS, In normal case, it wont toggle by clicking the element again. I think he was trying to achieve that toggling effect

Comment: @arjuncc yes you might be right but we are both guessing. OP should state what works, what he want's to achieve _and_ what didn't work with the approach. With the description given here it could simply be that the script is not loaded and that `.selectable()` doesn't work. I don't think it is but the facts in the question does make that possible

Comment: @RuneFS, You are right, It could also be possible a script error. That was what I understood from his question. I was guessing based on his comment 'i want when clicked on element its be selected and when again clicked on this, its be deselected'. So, I think he is the only one who could do make us know what he exactly want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

OK I hope my answer will help. Here, what you should do is to set your [metakey](http://api.jquery.com/event.metaKey/) to true on  `mouse down event`. In the sample code the event is [binded](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). I got this from stackoverflow itself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718493/how-to-implement-toggle-functionality-on-jquery-ui-selectable), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946462/jquery-ui-selectable-unselect-selected-item-on-click).

Now for your specific problem click the following link
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/nMrrW/)